# Kafka manual ackMode MANUAL_IMMEDIATE what if not acknowledge

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, spring-kafka

I use Spring KafKa anf I set ackMode to MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

```
props.setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

the scenario is that for some reason my app could not acknowledge (`acknowledgment.acknowledge()`) and just miss it without exception.

1- How can I set consumer retry for missed message 
2- How configure to call a function after max retry count that I configured reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation about `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`s](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#seek-to-current).

When the listener throws an exception, the error handler will perform the necessary seeks and re-fetch the record. You can set the number of attempts before giving up.

There is also [a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#seek-to-current) which can be used to send the failed record to another topic.

Comment: thanks for answer, is there any way that without throwing exception (after a timeout without acknowledgment) listener retry