# Not acknowledging the kafka message at all in MANUAL_IMMEDIATE mode

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I could not find any documentation related to this issue, hence the question.

What happens if `@KafkaListener` method does not call `acknowledgement.acknowledge()` at all when the `ackMode`is set to `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` but exits out of the method successfully without any exceptions.

We encountered this issue in one of our consumers and lost the message (precisely the offset moved, we had expected the offset to not move since we never called `acknowledgement.acknowledge()`), is this expected behaviour?

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530309/kafka-manual-ackmode-manual-immediate-what-if-not-acknowledge) seems to address the same issue but never received an answer as to what would happen when there are no exceptions, as I believe the error handler & recoverer come into play only when exceptions are thrown and not during message un-acknowledged situations.

Answer (score 4):

There are two pointers maintained by Kafka; the committed offset and the current position.

If you don't call `acknowledge()`, and exit normally, the committed offset won't be moved, but the position will; you will get the next records on the next `poll()`.

If you restart the application, you will get the same record(s) redelivered.

You must also set the Kafka consumer property `enable.auto.commmit` to `false` - spring-kafka (since 2.3) does this automatically, unless you have explicitly set it.

Comment: We did have the `enable.auto.commmit` set to `false` but the message was not read after the service was restarted

Comment: The framework will never commit any offsets with that setting. You can monitor commits by setting the `commitLogLevel` container property to INFO. Of course, if the next record is processed successfully, you will not get the "skipped" record again because committing the next offset will move the offset by 2.